# Pardot SDK for python after Feb 15 login change

Tags: oauth2, pardot, sdk

We are using Pardot SDK (package: Pypardot) to pull and update data from Pardot API (version 4).
Since the authentication change was implemented, the SDK method of Pardot is not supported anymore and it means that we need to recreate our whole API calls from scratch.
Is there any solution to use SF authentication alongside with Pardot SDK?

Comment: https://github.com/mneedham91/PyPardot4/issues/46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it yet myself, you might want to checkout PyPardotSF.

https://github.com/anelendata/PyPardotSF

Based on the documentation, this library should be a bit more feature-rich than the original as it supports both V3 and V4.

There is no mention yet of the V5 API, so if that's important to you then you may need to make adjustments and use what you can.